# How to configure the new Azure App service instead of Mobile Service From Android?

Tags: android, azure, mobile

1. I used Azure Mobile Services from My android app using URL and API key for SQL Database Access,but currently that Mobile app Services No longer Available.
2. Please Help me how to Configure with New App Services from Android App.

Code I Used for **Mobile service Config from Azure to android App**:

```
    // Mobile Service URL and key
    mClient_User = new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://****.azure-mobile.net/",
            "******************",
            this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());
```

[Link I referred for Migration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/)

Answer (score 1):

According to the document,

> Migrating a service just changes the underlying environment that hosts your mobile backend. It requires no code changes to either the mobile client or the mobile server project. If you use the automated migration option, this preserves your service.azure-mobile.net URL.

Specially per your issue, please check with the following points:

- Data scripts in Mobile Services have been changed to Easy Tables in Mobile Apps, please follow the https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/#_easytables to check whether you have finished the migration.
- Verify the data connection setting in your Mobile Apps on Azure portal, if there is not a configuration named `MS_TableConnectionString` existing, add a new one and reference to your Azure SQL database.
  [image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.